# Azure AD B2C Resource Owner Password Credentials Authentication

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

In my application I want to call Azure Web API using  Resource Owner Password Credential flow. I have implemented Azure AD b2c Auth for my Web API. I have created 2 Application in Azure, one for Web API and  Native client App for ROPC. I gave WEB Api Access in ROPC app. I followed [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-ropc?tabs=applications) and got the Token from ROPC app. But when i pass my ROPC token to Web API I am getting 401. I dont know how to pass the scope of my web api scope in ROPC Token Request. Any help would be appreciated

Thanks in Advance,
Subbiah K

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are requesting /token from Native APP (ROPC flow), you can add scopes in the request.

From the doc scope default set to

`openid <ApplicationId/ClientId> offline_access`

Modify this to like below to add scopes from Web API app. Make sure you should not put ClientId in scope

```
`openid https://tenant.onmicrosoft.com/hello/demo.read https://tenant.onmicrosoft.com/hello/user_impersonation offline_access`
```

Hope you already given API access (scopes) to Native Application.

Once you get access_token, that token will contain all the scopes you requested and you can send this to Web API to authorize.

Comment: Thanks Man, Its working. Can I use this flow inside Azure Web Job. I want to do some periodic work using Azure WQeb jb which internally callAzure ADB2c Web API.

Comment: Yes that is possible. And I guess this is the only option you have when it comes to web job.

Comment: this really helped me achieve my solution, thanks!